# Separating text from .txt into colums in listview (VB.net mobile)

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile

I want to separate each text into their own Column in VB.net.

How do I achieve this?

[image: Screen shots]

Each entree is seperated with "|" . My Code:

```
 Private Sub MenuItem3_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem3.Click
    Dim folder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
    Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("\My Expenses.txt")

        sw.WriteLine(DateTimePicker.Text + Space(1) & "|" & Subject.Text + Space(4) & "|" & Category.Text + Space(5) & "|" & Amount.Text + Space(4) & "|" & Peyment.Text)
        sw.Close()

    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of the compact framework are you using. I believe you want to look into using the [ListViewItemCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any mobile apps to experiment on at this moment, but I believe something like this is what you are after:

```
Private Sub MenuItem3_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem3.Click
  Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("\My Expenses.txt")
    For Each item As ListViewItem in ListView1
      Dim line As String = Nothing
      For Each entry As String in item.SubItems
        line.Append(entry & "|")
      Next For
      sw.WriteLine(line)
    Next For
    sw.Close()
  End Using
End Sub
```

I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do, but I think you are trying to get the column entries.

**Update:**

Now that you have saved the settings to a file, how would you get them back?

```
Private Sub PopulateListView()
  ListView1.Items.Clear()
  Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("\My Expenses.txt")
    While (-1 < sr.Peek())
      Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
      Dim item As New ListViewItem(line.Split("|"c))
      ListView1.Items.Add(item)
    End While
    sr.Close()
  End Using
End Sub
```

Naturally, your code may have special handling that is required, but this covers the basic read and write operations.

Comment: I beleive he is wanting to import the .txt file that he created, split it into seperate records and add it to his control's columns

Comment: Thanks jp2code. Mark Hall is right in what I am trying to achieve.

The current code produces some error for me, being:

Expression is of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView', which is not a collection type.

Basically,

I want the listview object to import a text.file that has each entrée separated by a pipe "|" and put each of them in a seperate column.

Comment: Reading it back is just the opposite of writing it out. I have edited my solution to add a reading routine.