# Saving Columns of listview in VB with separator

Tags: vb.net

So I have a listview which has two columns. the listview view is details.

I have successfully imported a file into the list view with correct splits. The code i used is,

`Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText( file path )
                While (-1 < sr.Peek())
                    Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
                    Dim item As New ListViewItem(line.Split(":"c))
                    ListView1.Items.Add(item)
                End While
                sr.Close()
            End Using`

So this imports the lines from my file to the program into correct columns with : as split.
Now I also have a option for users to add data from my program to the file the same way, I used this code,

```
     Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(file path)
    For Each item As ListViewItem in ListView1
      Dim line As String = Nothing
      For Each entry As String in item.SubItems
        line.Append(entry & ":")
      Next For
      sw.WriteLine(line)
    Next For
    sw.Close()
  End Using
```

Taken from : [Separating text from .txt into colums in listview (VB.net mobile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162262/separating-text-from-txt-into-colums-in-listview-vb-net-mobile)
But my bad, vb gives this error,

> Error 1   Expression is of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView', which is not a collection type.  C:\Users\xxxx\documents\visual studio 2012\xxxxx\Form1.vb   97

I am not sure why i am getting this error, is it because of my list views properties ?

I want to be able to save the data to the text file when user click a button.

Comment: `For Each entry As String in item.SubItems` is wrong - Items contain a collection of Subitems so you cant iterate it with a string varible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
For Each item As ListViewItem in ListView1
```

should be this:

```
For Each item As ListViewItem in ListView1.Items
```

and this line:

```
For Each entry As String in item.SubItems
```

should be this:

```
For Each entry As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem in item.SubItems
```

You then get a String from the Text property of the subitem.

Comment: For Each item As ListViewItem In listview1.Items
                Dim line As String = Nothing
                For Each entry As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In item.SubItems
                    line.Append(entry & ":")
                Next
                sw.WriteLine(line)
            Next
            sw.Close()
        End Using
but i get the error for line.append.
Error 1 'Append' is not a member of 'String' 101
Error 2 Operator '&' is not defined for types 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem' and 'String'.101

Is there any changes i should make for for the variable line ?

Comment: The change you should make is to read what I posted and follow the instructions provided.  I specifically stated that you get a String from the Text property of the subitem.  Where in that code are you doing that?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I juz used the reverse method by saving the text to the file and updating the listview.